# save file in array laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file

I'm trying to get request from my api client , in my request has items each item should have image witch is file
,how can I save image  when I'm loop in items?

my item data like so :

```
items:[
 {
      "image" : "1.png"
 }
  ]
```

That is my data , of course in my client side send this data as form data

Comment: Please check this link. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: You can loop on item, and fetch the image using `$image = $item->image_file;` then store it using `File::put($path, $image);` where $path is the string that has the location to your file.

Answer (score 0):

I've found new feature in laravel with we can create new file with `UploadedFile::createFromBase()` then web can easily get file  extension